# uint128_t does not name a type

Tags: c++, c, types, integer

I am porting some code from C to C++. During the conversion I encountered:

> `uint128_t` does not name a type

My compiler: gcc version 5.2.1
My operating system: Ubuntu 15.1

This compiled fine as C and I thought it would be resolved by including `stdint.h` but it has not. So far I have not tried anything else since there doesn't seem to be a lot of information on this error ([example](https://www.google.nl/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=uint128_t%20does%20not%20name%20a%20type&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=OUSKVsyaFom-oQfPx6mwAQ#channel=fs&q=uint128_t%20does%20not%20name%20a%20type&nirf=uint32_t%20does%20not%20name%20a%20type)). `uint128_t` is used throughout this entire program and is essential for the build, therefore I can not remove it, and I'm not sure about using a different integer type.

Below is an example of where and how it is used.

```
union {
    uint16_t  u16;
    uint32_t  u32;
    uint128_t u128;
} value;
```

Would it be okay to define a `uint128_t` or should I look at my compiler?

Comment: Too broad. 128 bit types are non-standard. Even `uint32_t` is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: I think the [standard suggests fixed-width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) upto 64-bits only, not more. You should find a compiler which provides software support for wider types or find a bignum library or write it yourself.

Comment: gcc knows `unsigned __int128` for some targets, but it's a non-standard extension.

Comment: @legends2k: Fixed-width types are optional. Only certain (i.e. `n*8; n=1..8`) `least` and `fast` types are mandatory.

Comment: I believe g++ refrains from defining `uint128_t` as this would require an ABI breaking change to `std::uintmax_t`.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the same GCC on the same platform would know `uint128_t` when compiling C but not know it when compiling C++ code. Are you sure you've told us everything?

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, indeed. The standard is quite particular about "integral types", and so if you just add new integral types willy nilly, that has non-local effects all over the language. So `__int128` is not strictly an "integral type" in the sense of the type taxonomy.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html With a `typdef __int128 uint128_t`, the compiler should tell if your target supports it.

Comment: The link you provided helped; __int128_t was recognized, however, unsigned __int128_t raised the same does not name type error. If I `typedef __int128 uint128_t` I lose the unsigned part, which might cause problems.

Comment: I think you can say `typedef unsigned __int128 uint128_t;`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: `typedef`ing an apparently unsigned name to a signed type is likely a very bad idea.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

GCC has builtin support for the types [`__int128`, `unsigned __int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html), `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` (the last two are undocumented). Use them to define your own types:

```
typedef __int128 int128_t;
typedef unsigned __int128 uint128_t;
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `__mode__(TI)`:

```
typedef int int128_t __attribute__((mode(TI)));
typedef unsigned int uint128_t __attribute__((mode(TI)));
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Modes.html):

> `TImode`
>
> “Tetra Integer” (?) mode represents a sixteen-byte integer.

Sixteen byte = 16 * CHAR_BIT >= 128.

Comment: Or restate what @AndreaCorbellini said a bit differently: a 128 bit integral type is a GNU compiler specific feature. (1.) If you want to keep your code portable you will have to create header files that autodetect these compiler features. (2.) setting/getting the value will work but your-mileage-may-vary when using arithmetic-operations/functions (not to mention all the type conversion issues).

Answer (score 6):

> *I thought this would be resolved by including `stdint.h` but it has not.*

Well, it may not.

First to check the C++ header, `cstdint`, from C++14, chapter § 18.4.1,

> ```
> namespace std {.....
>
> typedef unsigned integer type uint8_t; // optional
> typedef unsigned integer type uint16_t; // optional
> typedef unsigned integer type uint32_t; // optional
> typedef unsigned integer type uint64_t; // optional
> .....
> ```

and,

> The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard. [..]

Then quote the `C11` standard, chapter §7.20.1.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> 2. The typedef name `uintN_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width `N` and no
>      padding bits. Thus, `uint24_t` denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of
>      exactly `24` bits.
> 3. **These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with
>      widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a
>      two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.**

So, here we notice two things.

1. An implementation is not mandated to provide support for the fixed-width `int`s.
2. Standard limits the width upto `64`, as we see it. having a width more than that is once again not mandated in the standard. You need to check the documentation of the environment in use.

Comment: I see, but is there a way to define a 128 bit int?

Comment: The question is about porting to C++, so a quote from the C++ standard might be more helpful. Pointing out that the original code uses optional constructs is more suitable as a commant than as an answer.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck How about now?

Comment: Disagree that the standard _limits_ width up to `64`.

Comment: @chux I got your point. Shall I write "standard definition is limited upto the width of 64 bytes...". Will that be any good?

Comment: Perhaps "_Exact-width_, _Minimum-width_ and _Fastest minimum-width_ greater than 64 bits are not required. `uint128_t` is not necessarily implemented." or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by other answer, C++ standard does not require 128 bit integer to be available, nor to be `typedef`ed as `uint128_t` even if present. If your compiler/architecture does not support 128 bit integers and you need them, you could use boost to emulate them:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html

I think that the boost library will automatically use the native type if available

Comment: Or perhaps [this implementation](https://github.com/calccrypto/uint128_t) of a uint128_t for C++ 11 or newer.