# Is it always safe to use std::vector<size_t> with different integer types?

Tags: c++

Trying to receive a vector with unknown big values I came up with a solution I thought to be entirely wrong: I supposed when an element of the `std::vector<size_t>` is assigned first to a small value and then to a big one there could be an error or data loss because the type for the entire vector was already set and some space in memory was arranged.

However the following code works:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

int main(){

    std::vector<size_t> vec;

    // Fixing size and adding small number which 
    // I suppose would set type as a small one, 
    // i.e. int 
    vec.resize(2);
    int i = 0;
    std::fill(vec.begin(),vec.end(),i);    

    // add a big number that should not fit smaller type
    unsigned long long bignum = 18446744073709551614;
    vec.push_back(bignum);

    std::cout<<vec[0]<<" "<<vec[1]<<" "<<vec[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<typeid(vec[0]).name()<<std::endl
    <<typeid(vec[1]).name()<<std::endl<<typeid(vec[2]).name()<<std::endl;

    // cell 0 was already initialized with int, trying to make oveflow
    vec[0] = 18446744073709551613;

    std::cout<<vec[0]<<" "<<vec[1]<<" "<<vec[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<typeid(vec[0]).name()<<std::endl
    <<typeid(vec[1]).name()<<std::endl<<typeid(vec[2]).name()<<std::endl;

    return 1;   
}
```

However, the output does not contain type names, maybe because of my compiler:

```
$ ./a.out
0 0 18446744073709551614
m
m
m
18446744073709551613 0 18446744073709551614
m
m
m
```

So is it safe for all compilers and can I freely operate with `vector::<size_t>` (send to functions, etc) when I don't know the integer types used?

Comment: should be safe. size_t is actually uint32_t or uint64_t or even uint16_t depends on target machine architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector<size_t>` means a vector whose entries are all `size_t`.  If you try to store a value that is not a `size_t`, it will be implicitly converted to `size_t` before being stored.  This could involve data loss if the original value was an integer outside the range of [`0`, `SIZE_MAX`].

Your question suggests that you imagine the vector is storing objects of various different types, but that does not happen.

Note: `size_t` typically represents the size of the largest possible allocatable unit. Perhaps it would be better to use a type that more reflects the source of values you are storing, e.g. `uint64_t`.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I've just misunderstood everything, because I thought that the following: _The size_t type is the unsigned integer type that is the result of the sizeof operator (and the offsetof operator), so it is guaranteed to be big enough to contain the size of the biggest object your system can handle (e.g., a static array of 8Gb).

The size_t type may be bigger than, equal to, or smaller than an unsigned int, and your compiler might make assumptions about it for optimization."_ means that `size_t` adjusts variable size to contain the result. But it's just a type

Comment: @Slowpoke I don't see how you get "size_t adjsts variable size" out of the quoted text. *Different systems* might have different sizes of size_t, but it doesn't change during a program run

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've indeed misunderstood that quite some time ago and believed that sizeof was applied somehow to make variable to contain the data.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not safe.

It's only work because you put a `int >= 0`. `size_t` is `unsigned` so if you try to put negative value you will have `negative_value % 2**n` where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type.

---

The element in your vector are `size_t`. When you fill it with `i`, you ask to the compiler to cast a `int` into a `size_t`. This is not "safe".

---

```
vec[0] = 18446744073709551613;
```

And here this is safe because vec[0] is a `size_t`.

---

Beware that [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is designed to handle... size. So the max value that can handle a `size_t` is not fixed. If you want stock integer. Use [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

Comment: put a negative value to unsigned int will not have undefined behavior.

Comment: @DUJiaen My bad, I was thought that it was like C about this. But it's not "safe" either.

Answer (score 4):

additionally to the answer by @Stargateur, the best portable bet is `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`. They are guaranteed to be the biggest integer types available on the platform.

There might also be compiler specific extensions, such as `__int128_t`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588884/4593721) gives some information about 128 bit builtins in the gcc. Do note that `std::intmax_t` will stll be 64 bit.

Comment: gcc typically provides `intmax_t` as 64-bit, and `int128_t` as 128-bit integer types (which does not comply with the standard)

Comment: @M.M, OP didn't specify compiler, but thanks, I will add a note that there might be compiler specific extensions