# How to fill a set where items are 8 char? (std::set<char [8]>)

Tags: c++, string, set, unordered-set

I'd like to fill a set in which each item is 8 bytes (can be 8 readable char or binary data). It seems that

```
std::unordered_set<char [8]> d;
d.insert("abcdefgh");

std::set<char [8]> d2;
d2.insert("abcdefgh");

std::string s = "Hello this is a string, the first 16 char will be inserted in the set";
d2.insert(s.substr(0,16));
```

doesn't work. Why? The error seems to be, among others,

> The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

(for the `unordered_set` case).

**Is there a way to make a set of 8-bytes items?**

Note: I'd like to avoid `std::unordered_set<std::string> d` because here it's really 8 data bytes per item, and I would like to keep it simple and small (the set will have millions of items). I would like to avoid another layer of memory used by `std::string` structure itself / pointers, etc.

Note2: I am using a `set` / `unordered_set`, and not a vector, or anything else, because I would like super fast membership lookup.

Comment: Note that you're all but guaranteed that `std::string` will use Small String Optimization here, so no dynamic allocations, but yes, it's still overkill on size. You might consider someone's `fixed_string` or similar.

Comment: Since arrays are delicate soap bubbles that degenerate into a pointer without nary any provocation, I've found doing `struct Char8 { char data[8]; };` to be a reasonable way to avoid the soap bubble problem.

Comment: @Eljay: looks interesting. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Eljay How about `using Char8 = std::array<char, 8>;`? Gives you the benefit of `std::begin`/`std::end` support and similar.

Comment: `"abcdefgh"` are 9 bytes.

Comment: You might get better performance packing the 8 chars into an integral type: `std::unordered_set<std::uint64_t>` (assuming your bytes are indeed 8 bits).

Comment: Nice solution @KlitosKyriacou. If I want one day to use 16 bytes, is there a `uint128`?

Comment: It depends on your compiler. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588650/uint128-t-does-not-name-a-type.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use `std::array<char, 8>` instead;

You must define a hasher:

```
struct hash_char_8 {
    std::size_t operator()(std::array<char, 8> arr) {

    }
}
```

Or just use `std::set`.

And you need to convert the literal to the array:

```
#include <algorithm>
    // std::copy

std::array<char, 8> to_char_8(char const literal[9]) {
    std::array<char, 8> a;
    std::copy(literal, literal + 8, a.begin());

    return a;
}
```

The code using it:

```
std::unordered_set<std::array<char, 8>, hash_char_8> d;
d.insert(to_char_8("abcdefgh"));
```

Comment: It seems that your `to_char_8` is not correct, since `std::array` doesn't have a constructor with iterators `begin`/`end`. You have to use `std::copy` to init it properly.

Comment: Prefer to use `uint8_t`, as `char` can be `signed, unsigned, char` or larger than 8 bits.